# What is the equivalent annotation for the old map/@attr in AngularDart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

The [AngularDart tutorial](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial/wiki/Creating-a-Custom-Component) (at of the time of this writing), recommends binding component fields to attributes like this:

```dart
map: const {
  'max-rating' : '@maxRating',
  'rating' : '<=>rating'
}
```

However, I see also that Angular has `@NgOneWay`, `@NgTwoWay`, and others. I can't find the annotation for `@`. Which annotation do I want if I want the same semantics as `@maxRating` ?

Apparently:

`@NgOneWay` == `=>`

`@NgTwoWay` == `<=>`

`@NgOneWayOneTime` == `=>!`

`???` == `@`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [`@NgAttr`](http://ci.angularjs.org/view/Dart/job/angular.dart-master/javadoc/angular.core/NgAttr.html) is what you are looking for.

For callbacks there is also [`@NgCallback`](http://ci.angularjs.org/view/Dart/job/angular.dart-master/javadoc/angular.core/NgCallback.html) == `&` - just to complete your list.