# data binding inside directive constructor

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to bind a function (this.getData) to a variable (rating) within the constructor of a directive:

```dart
@NgDirective(
    selector: '[spreadsheet]',
    map: const {
    'rating' : '<=>rating'
    })

class Spreadsheet {
  dom.Element element;

  Function rating;

  getData(){
    return context.callMethod(r'$', [this.element])
    .callMethod('handsontable', ['getData']);
  }

  Spreadsheet(this.element) {
  context.callMethod(r'$', [this.element])
   .callMethod('handsontable', [new JsObject.jsify(options)]);

  **rating = this.getData;**
  }
}
```

and it seems that "rating" is not assigned with "this.getData" when I access it:

```dart
<p spreadsheet rating="rating"></p>
{{rating()}}
```

the "rating" is null. This is not the case when I do the binding for example when mouse enters the element:

```dart
...
Spreadsheet(this.element) {
   element
  ..onMouseEnter.listen((ev){this.rating = this.getData;});
...
```

and the binding occurs fine when mouse enters the element (rating is not null). How this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

If you assign the function in the constructor you won't need

```
 'rating' : '<=>rating'
```

You can call any method from your expressions in markup.
The map or annotations ([What is the annotation equivalent of map: const {'foo':'&foo'} in AngularDart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422866), [What is the equivalent annotation for the old map/@attr in AngularDart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422743)) are only for synchronizing attribute and field values.

If you also want to be able to assign the function from the outside you need `@` instead of `<=>` or `@NgCallback('rating')` (see [What is the equivalent annotation for the old map/@attr in AngularDart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422743))

You should set `publishAs: 'ctrl'` and call the method using `{{ctrl.rating()}}`

Comment: can I expose a directive as by 'publishAs'? What I want to achieve is the reverse of "NgCallBak", i.e., I want to be able to call a method of a component/directive from outside to get the data from.

Comment: Your comment is to abstract for me.
Can you extend you question with a simple example which describes what you actually try to achieve `<outer><inner></inner></outer>` I want that inner calls xxx on outer...